# Is there is any way to get the Auth.userdata data return by facebook ( single sign-on) in salesforce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, single-sign-on

Auth data received in debug is  null

> DEBUG|DATA:::::UserData:[attributeMap={id=1124567878765, name=test ,
>   sfdc_networkid=98394580535tF}, email=null, firstName=null,
>   fullName=test ABC, identifier=112942424234, lastName=null, link=null,
>   locale=null, provider=Facebook, siteLoginUrl=null, username=null]